# My Raycast hit the object behind the collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm making an FPS game on Unity. I have an enemy object with a box collider and rigid body, and I turn on the isTrigger on Box Collider. However, I don't know why but I couldn't shoot the enemy. The Raycast hit always hit the object behind of the enemy. But, when I turn off the isTrigger on the enemy Box Collider, I could hit the object, but the movement is so weird. Could anyone help me how to make the Raycast could hit a trigger box collider? Thank you so much

Raycast Code

```
void BulletFired() {
        RaycastHit hit;
        print("shoot");
        if (Physics.Raycast(mainCam.transform.position, mainCam.transform.forward, out hit)) {
            print(hit.transform.gameObject.name);
            if (hit.transform.tag == Tags.ENEMY_TAG) {
                print(hit.transform.tag);
                hit.transform.GetComponent<HealthScript>().ApplyDamage(damage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does your `BoxCollider` affect mouvement?

Comment: @Savaria when I turn off the BoxCollider isTrigger, when the enemy approach me and try to hit me, the enemy will bounce away from my player and the attack will not reach my player. But I could hit the enemy with the Raycast.

Comment: @Nicholas Does anything else modify your collider? And are you sure raycast will hit enemy when there's only a single raycast pointing `forward`? Usually people need a perspective of vision.

Comment: Add a debug line to your raycast to check if it hits enemy. `Debug.DrawLine` could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for everyone who helps me on finding this solution. It means a lot for me.
Turn out, I need to uncheck the physics setting of Reuse Collision Callbacks in order to make it works. Thank you everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

Normally `Raycast` hits `isTrigger` objects just fine. If it really is ignoring the target when it's isTrigger, maybe you are using `Physics.queriesHitTriggers` or `queryTriggerInteraction` explained here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

It would help if you provide your `Raycast` line of code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've already add the snippet of my Raycast

Comment: Actually, I could only hit the enemy from their first position on respawn when the isTrigger is on. But when the Enemy starts moving, The raycast always pass the enemy and hit the object behind it

Comment: @Nicholas probably your collider is not following your enemy?

Comment: @knh190 I've try to play the game while watching the scene and the collider is following my enemy